# Why does this function to return a node from a binary tree with the given key always return NULL?

Tags: c++, pointers, search, tree, binary-tree

The C++ function in question is:

```
Node* returnSearchNode(int key, Node* Ptr){
    if(Ptr != NULL){
        if(Ptr->data==key){
           return Ptr;
        }
        else{
            Node* foundNode = returnSearchNode(key, Ptr->left);
            if(foundNode == NULL) {
                foundNode = returnSearchNode(key, Ptr->right);
            }
            return foundNode;
        }
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Take for example this tree: 
[image: eg tree 1]

The returned node is stored in the main function as:

```
Node* target = returnSearchNode(key, root);
```

Even if I enter 15 or 31 as the key, which both exist in the tree, the function always returns NULL. What is the problem with the function here?

Comment: For your simple example tree, use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement to see what really happens.

Comment: And you could make your code a little more effective by checking if `key` is smaller or larger than `Ptr->data` to decide which sub-tree to search.

Comment: Please make the problem *reproducible*, i.e. add the necessary code that creates a tree, calls your function, and outputs the result. That way we can see the problem by running it.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your code and execised with the tree structure you have given, look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

Node* returnSearchNode(int key, Node* Ptr){
    if(Ptr != NULL){
        if(Ptr->data==key){
           return Ptr;
        }
        else{
            Node* foundNode = returnSearchNode(key, Ptr->left);
            if(foundNode == NULL) {
                foundNode = returnSearchNode(key, Ptr->right);
            }
            return foundNode;
        }
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

std::vector<Node> generate_tree()
{
    std::vector<Node> nodes{8};
    nodes[0].data = 48;
    nodes[0].left = &nodes[1];
    nodes[0].right = &nodes[2];
    nodes[1].data = 38;
    nodes[1].left = &nodes[3];
    nodes[1].right = nullptr;
    nodes[2].data = 60;
    nodes[2].left = &nodes[4];
    nodes[2].right = nullptr;
    nodes[3].data = 31;
    nodes[3].left = &nodes[5];
    nodes[3].right = &nodes[6];
    nodes[4].data = 56;
    nodes[4].left = nullptr;
    nodes[4].right = nullptr;
    nodes[5].data = 15;
    nodes[5].left = nullptr;
    nodes[5].right = &nodes[7];
    nodes[6].data = 34;
    nodes[6].left = nullptr;
    nodes[6].right = nullptr;
    nodes[7].data = 25;
    nodes[7].left = nullptr;
    nodes[7].right = nullptr;
    return nodes;
}

void find_node(int key, Node* Ptr)
{
    auto *node = returnSearchNode(key, Ptr);
    if (node)
        std::cout << "found Node " << node << " with key " << node->data << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NULL" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto nodes = generate_tree();
    find_node(15, &nodes[0]);
    find_node(31, &nodes[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything is OK, output:

```
found Node 0x5587892ceee8 with key 15
found Node 0x5587892ceeb8 with key 31
```

I suspect your 'data' is not just an integer but a pointer like `void *data` that likely gives you in most cases incorrect comparison results

Comment: I have declared data as int.

Comment: @RAZOR, then your tree is malformed